# Why did my stroke drop from one side of the layer after I re-sized the canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a .psd file with a background layer that I added a stroke to. Adding the stroke worked fine until I had to re-size my canvas. After I re-sized the canvas my stroke now only appears on three sides of my layer. I have tried to edit the stroke, even tried to delete it from my layer but I cannot get anything to work.

Why did my stroke drop from one side of the layer after I re-sized the canvas? How do I fix this? I am running Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.

Comment: Hi gacto, I edited your question title to match the question being asked. If you want to delete a stroke that is a layer style, just right click on the layer -> clear layer style but I don't think that is what you're looking for in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To quickly fix this**, just make a new layer that will be a background layer. Fill the new layer with a color. This makes the new layer fill the bounds of the resized canvas. When you add a stroke to the new background layer, the stroke will properly fit the resized canvas.

**The reason this happened**. When you resized your canvas, the background layer is still accounting for the original canvas size because that is the size of that layer. This means that whichever side you cropped, the background & stroke is extended past the crop.

You can test this by grabbing your crop tool. You will see the missing stroke is cropped out.

Comment: ok i didn't realize the layer retained the original canvas size. that makes sense now. your solution worked perfect. thanks for the help.